# creating dojox chart with tooltip returns error: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand source

Tags: dojo, tooltip, dojox.charting

Dojo version: 1.10.4 downloaded 11/24/2015
When I create a new Tooltip, there is an error returned:
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand source
thrown from dojox/lang/utils.js line 46
if(x in source && !(x in empty)){...}
where source is the text, "default", but it is expecting an object. 
The text, "default" appears to be from the call to create the Tooltip,
indicated in the code below. 
(I've removed code that I think is unnecessary to understand the problem.)

```
require([ "dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/widget/Legend", 
"dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip", 
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Bars", "dojox/charting/plot2d/ClusteredBars", 
"dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedBars", "dojo/domReady!"], 
function(Chart, Legend, Tooltip){

var barChart = new Chart("WPDDashboard_DojoBarChart3_1",
{ title: 'Finance Comparison', titleFont: 'bold 100% Arial});

barChart.addPlot("default", {
type: 'ClusteredBars' , gap: 5, stroke: {
color: 'black', width: 2}, fill: '#3366cc', shadow: {
dx: 2, dy: 2}});

barChart.connectToPlot("default" ........);

barChart.addAxis(.......);

//I think this is the offending line
var tip = new Tooltip(barChart, "default");

barChart.render();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ordering of the required objects doesn't line up with the declaration. You're requiring Chart, Legend, Default, and then Tooltip while you're declaring Chart, Legend, and then Tooltip. So what you've done is you named the Default chart to Tooltip and tried using it. Try fixing the order and that should work.